# Is $T(f)=f'$ where $f$ is infinitely differentiable an additive transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If the map is defined as  $T:V \rightarrow V$ by $T(f)=f'$ where $f$ is infinitely differentiable. 
I am trying to show that $T$ is a linear transformation. 
I understand how to show that it is homogenous but I am struggling to show that it is additive. Please help show that it is additive.

Comment: Additivity means $(f+g)'=f'+g'$.

Answer (score 1):

You should have learned, in Calculus I, that (f+ g)'= f'+ g' and that (cf)'= cf' for any constant, c.